# How Can i Select all using SendKeys in Vb6

Tags: vb6

I use these lines to Select all text and copy it to the clipboard from the active window
but no text is Selected, so how can I select text using vb6 and sendkeys function

- I'm using win 10

```
Call SendKeys("^A", True)
Call SendKeys("^c", True)
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce6070a0-7995-4f3e-b3bf-5caabfee8fce/sendkeys-and-windows-10?forum=msdnmagazine

Comment: Are you trying to select from a TextBox?

Comment: no from any active window when i press the shortcut

Comment: Active window from your VB app? Or an outside application.